# excel to access using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

net and I'm looking for a way to import excel sheet to ms access and I found this site(http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/79/import-data-from-excel-to-access-with-asp-net), then I use the code with some modification on it and here's the code:

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile As String = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\System3.0\System3.0.accdb"
    Dim Access As String = provider & dataFile
    Dim Excel As String = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
    Dim connect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & Excel & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml; HRD = YES"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connect)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MS Access;Database=" & Access & "].[Student] SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class

Problem is that I got this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid argument." in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Please help me find the problem...thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't believe you need to concatenate 'provider' and 'dataFile', as the example you linked to does not do this.

Comment: ah yes your right, I just test if I could use it this way. I'm using a local database while they are using a server after all...so I cant use these code this way?...

Comment: Not sure, haven't used OleDB in a while. The provider is already established in the connection string so I would assume that just referencing the Access DB the way they provided in their example would do precisely what you want it to do.